# In 10k mod notifications show notifications only for unacted on flags

Tags: feature-request, notifications, 10k-tools

### Background

When a new flag is received for attention by 10k+ users a red 1 appears on the status bar

[image]

However, this notification persists even after I have acted on the flag where other people still need to act on it.

### The problem

This means that if I act on a flag, the notification remains and I mentally start ignoring it, then if that flag is dismissed and a new flag raised while I'm not looking then I won't realise a new flag has been raised. It's also irritating to have notifications that I can't deal with

### The request

- Only count flags I haven't yet handled in the notification

*or*

- Once opened hide the notification until next flag arrives

Comment: Also not displaying the number at all once you've hit the daily review  limit would be nice.

Comment: Oh nooo it's 2 now (sigh... going to handle the flags)

Comment: *Hide the notification until the next flag arrives.* - This should be doable. I've sketched an algorithm that does this in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231428/191131).