# Review counter still shows number when done reviewing the maximum amount a day

Tags: bug

I mailed the Stack Overflow crew about this problem, they said they've not heard about it before and they redirected me to meta, so here I am.

The review counter shows me the number 5, but I already finished my review tasks:
[image]

Above "Thank you" text appeared, after clicking the orange rectangle with "5" in it.
Should this be fixed or is it functioning as it should?

My opinion: The counter should check if the maximum review count has been reached for that user, if not show the review counter. If it has been reached: make it invisible.

Comment: Related request; [In 10k mod notifications show notifications only for unacted on flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214224/in-10k-mod-notifications-show-notifications-only-for-unacted-on-flags)

Comment: @RichardTingle Ah thanks, so it has been sort of noticed, but the link you sent is for users with 10k or more reputation?

Comment: The crew told me they didn't know about it, strange, I will delete this question.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg Duplicates can be helpful, if you couldn't easily find those questions then this post will point the way to them for future users

Comment: dupes are usually good at being signposts redirecting to the hard-to-find questions