# Review number is constantly "1"

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

First of all, my apologies if it looks like a duple of [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many), but since this question dates from more than 2 years, I thought it could be worth mentioning here.

I have this number "1" since last week:

[image: 1 review]

And when I click on it, I go to this page:

[image: Cleared queue]

First I thought it will disapear by itself, but since it still there, I thought it is probably a bug that I might report.

---

**EDIT:** The answer of the [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many) question says:

> This indicator is shown only to moderators and users who've gained access to the moderator tools.

As I didn't reach the requested 2k rep points, I did not have access to the moderator tools.

You can see I have not access to moderator tools: [image]
[image: privilege]

Comment: It is still a duplicate. Nothing has changed in the meantime.

Comment: You have. It is a beta site with lower thresholds. See [privileges](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: @PatrickHofman, your links says "access to moderator tools": 2000 rep points. I have less than that.

Comment: On your site, the [first review queue you get access to is at 350](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

Comment: Also see the last *edit* in the question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230833/245360

Comment: OK @Cai. I will notice this to the moderators.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Thought it's not a dupe, but it is. Users without the "access to moderator tools" but with the privilege to make reviews will simply see only items they can, in theory, review. It is still cached, and it still showing items you already reviewed and waiting for others to review before they're taken away from the count.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yes indeed this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230802/343696) is a little confusing as "access to moderator tools" doesn't mean "access to moderator tools" privilege, but all people that can do petty moderating stuff.